# How do I remove the "Personalize this Page" option in WSS 3 with feature code?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

How can I remove the "Personalize this Page" option in WSS 3.0?  I'd like to do it in code with a feature at the web application level if possible.

Comment: "Personalize this Page" might also be known as "personal view".  I think MOSS has an admin setting for this so I know it can be done, I just have to do it in code for WSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a **permission** and can be accessed in the web UI of WSS:

Site Settings > People and Groups (under Users and Perms) > Site Permissions (left quick launch bar) > Settings > Permission Levels

Under each Permission Level there is a long list of permissions to include.  At the bottom uncheck the items under Personal Permissions (mainly "Manage Personal Views").

I'm doing research on how to do it in code but our project requires custom user group administration so we just won't give them the option to Manage Personal Views.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the 'Personalize this Page' option will only be visable on pages containing web part zones that allow personalization. If you are using customised page layouts then you could set the 'AllowPersonalization' property to false on your web part zones.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could enforce the shared view, thus disabling personalizations on your page.
To accomplish this, do the following in any webpart, in the overriden OnLoad():

```
if (WebPartManager.Personalization.Scope == PersonalizationScope.User)
{
    WebPartManager.Personalization.ToggleScope();
}
```

However, this is not generally considered best practice because it could potentially affect the behavior of other webparts in your page.

Answer (score 0):

It CAN be done and pretty easily. Open up Welcome.ascx in `c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES`

and underneath  `<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="ID_PersonalizePage"`
add `Visible="False"`

works perfectly but will change it globally for all sites. Add the same code to any of the other sections if wanted.