# Sharepoint Personalization

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the “Personalize this Page” option in WSS 3 with feature code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663828/how-do-i-remove-the-personalize-this-page-option-in-wss-3-with-feature-code)

Hi,

I have to take out the **"personalize this page"** from the login drop down on the sharepoint site, at the top right hand corner.

How can I do that?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Post a separate question describing the permission issues you have. **You should to sort them out as soon as possible**, because this is not the only time they cause a problem. Then hide the *Personalize this Page* item by configuring permission levels http://stackoverflow.com/q/663828/95.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This menu only appears when you have webpart zone with AllowPersonalization=true attributes.
If you want to completely disable this functionality you can remove "Manage Personal Views" (or something similar) from the default permission levels.